# Textfile-parsing function fails to compile owing to type-mismatch error

Tags: rust, text-parsing, lifetime, type-mismatch, borrow-checker

I'm trying to parse a simple config text file, which contains one three-word entry per line, laid out as follows:

```
ITEM name value
ITEM name value
//etc.
```

I've reproduced the function which does the parsing (and the subsequent compilation error) here (and [on the Rust Playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=871c08ed1a38630130d1&version=stable)):

```
pub fn parse(path: &Path) -> config_struct {

    let file = File::open(&path).unwrap();
    let reader = BufReader::new(&file);
    let line_iterator = reader.lines();
    let mut connection_map = HashMap::new();
    let mut target_map = HashMap::new();

    for line in line_iterator {

        let line_slice = line.unwrap();
        let word_vector: Vec<&str> = line_slice.split_whitespace().collect();

        if word_vector.len() != 3 { continue; }

        match word_vector[0] {
            "CONNECTION" => connection_map.insert(word_vector[1], word_vector[2]),
            "TARGET" => target_map.insert(word_vector[1], word_vector[2]),
            _ => continue,
        }
    }

    config_struct { connections: connection_map, targets: target_map }
}

pub struct config_struct<'a>  {
    // <name, value>
    connections: HashMap<&'a str, &'a str>,
    // <name, value>
    targets: HashMap<&'a str, &'a str>,
}


src/parse_conf_file.rs:23:3: 27:4 error: mismatched types:
 expected `()`,
    found `core::option::Option<&str>`
(expected (),
    found enum `core::option::Option`) [E0308]
src/parse_conf_file.rs:23 match word_vector[0] {
src/parse_conf_file.rs:24   "CONNECTION" => connection_map.insert(word_vector[1], word_vector[2]),
src/parse_conf_file.rs:25   "TARGET" => target_map.insert(word_vector[1], word_vector[2]),
src/parse_conf_file.rs:26   _ => continue,
src/parse_conf_file.rs:27 }
```

In essence, I seem to have created a `match` statement that expects an empty tuple, and also finds the contents of a `Vec<&str>` to be wrapped in an `Option`!

NB. This post originally contained two questions (that I'd believed were one error manifesting itself differently), but as-per advice in the comments I've split it into two separate posts. The latter post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621567/textfile-parsing-function-fails-to-compile-owing-to-lifetime-borrow-error).

Comment: @Shepmaster Ah, sorry. Thanks for the advice - and for the links. Can't seem to create an example that executes on the Rust Playpen (it's virtualising File I/O, isn't it?), but have managed to produce the two compilation errors nevertheless, [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=871c08ed1a38630130d1&version=stable) and [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b07ddb3f7a156866188b&version=stable); do you think I should try to split my original into two separate posts for the sake of future readers, or leave it as it is now that it has already been answered?

Comment: *it's virtualising File I/O, isn't it?* - I don't think it's virtualized, but it is running in a sandbox. You can easily open `/etc/hosts` for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original problem is just that you have a non-`()` expression at the end of your loop body. Your `match` expression has type `Option<&str>` (because that is the return type of `HashMap::insert`), not type `()`. This problem is solved by simply putting a semicolon after the match expression:

```
match word_vector[0] {
    "CONNECTION" => connection_map.insert(word_vector[1], word_vector[2]),
    "TARGET" => target_map.insert(word_vector[1], word_vector[2]),
    _ => continue,
};
```

> For the latter, isn't word_vector populated with owned objects that don't point to line_slice?

No, which is precisely the issue. `word_vector` contains elements of type `&str`, i.e. borrowed strings. These point into `line_slice`, which only lives until the end of the current loop iteration. You probably want to convert them to `String`s (using `String::from`) before inserting them into the map.

Comment: Thanks very much - really helpful explanations! I've split the question into two parts though, as @Shepmaster advised; don't suppose you'd care to move the latter part of your answer over to the new question, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621567/textfile-parsing-function-fails-to-compile-owing-to-lifetime-borrow-error)?